# Convert String.split() result to Scala list

Tags: scala, collections

What is the means to convert the following java String[] to a Scala List?

```
val trimmedList : List[String] = str.split("\\n")).map (_.trim)    // Missing some code here, does not compile
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For simplicity, use `toList`:

```
val trimmedList: List[String] = str.split("\\n").map(_.trim).toList
```

For complexity, use `breakOut` (which avoids creating an intermediate collection from `map`):

```
import collection.breakOut
val trimmedList: List[String] = str.split("\\n").map(_.trim)(breakOut)
```

Comment: thx.  The actual problem is that I had two right parentheses after the split (take a look..)  . I have not become accustomed to IJ's parser error reporting and tend to misinterpret. The "toList" was trivial at that point.